# I just created a simple calculator app but when I input a decimal number the application crashes

Tags: android

Here is my code for the add function.

```
    public void add(View v)
{
    EditText  e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
     long num1,num2,result;
    num1=Long.parseLong(e1.getText().toString());
    num2=Long.parseLong(e2.getText().toString());
    result=num1+num2;
    tv.setText(Long.toString(result));

}
```

Comment: **How** does it crash? Mind to add your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Calculator.class:------------------

```
public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText edt1;
private EditText edt2;
private TextView tv_res;
private Button b_cal;

Float num1,num2,result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    tv_res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_res);
    b_cal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_cal);
    b_cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            num1 = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Float.parseFloat(edt2.getText().toString());
            result = num1 + num2;
            tv_res.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        }
    });
}
}
```

calculator.xml:------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter First Number"
    android:id="@+id/edt1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="+"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Second Number"
    android:id="@+id/edt2"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:hint="=" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_res"
    android:hint="Result" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/b_cal"
    android:text="Calculate"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your datatype from `long` to `double`, will fix your problem because you cannot parse a floating point value to a long.